# How to uncheck all breakpoints in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Is there a method to uncheck all breakpoints in Eclipse?

[image: all breakpoints]

Comment: The answer by Aakash is the one you are looking for. The others skip breakpoints which is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. Select all the checkboxes (Ctrl + A or Command + A).
2. Right click and choose disable to uncheck all or click Remove all to remove from list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Select the Remove All command [ Remove All Breakpoints ] to remove
>   all breakpoints from the Breakpoints View.

Source : http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-removeall_viewaction.htm

I think this doc got what you need !

Comment: You can't just link to a document. Links disappear. Quote the relevant part while including the link.

Comment: True that, my bad ! Editing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going under the `Run` menu, and clicking `Skip All Breakpoints` checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Note OP not asked for skipping. OP asked how to unselect/select.